# Spline Interpolation with Python

Tags: python, interpolation, spline, cubic

I wrote the following code to perform a spline interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

x1 = [1., 0.88,  0.67,  0.50,  0.35,  0.27, 0.18,  0.11,  0.08,  0.04,  0.04,  0.02]
y1 = [0., 13.99, 27.99, 41.98, 55.98, 69.97, 83.97, 97.97, 111.96, 125.96, 139.95, 153.95]

x = np.array(x1)
y = np.array(y1)

new_length = 25
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

but I am getting:

```
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

in `interpolate.py`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried running your code and got `name 'np' is not defined`. Is this your whole program?

Comment: No, you need to import: numpy as np, scipy as sp, scipy.interpolate

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [scipy documentation on scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

> scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', axis=-1, copy=True, bounds_error=True, fill_value=np.nan)
>
> x : array_like. A 1-D array of monotonically increasing real values.
>
> ...

The problem is that the x values are not [monotonically increasing](http://planetmath.org/MonotonicallyIncreasing.html). In fact they are monotonically decreasing. Let me know if this works and if its still the computation you are looking for.:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x1 = sorted([1., 0.88, 0.67, 0.50, 0.35, 0.27, 0.18, 0.11, 0.08, 0.04, 0.04, 0.02])
y1 = [0., 13.99, 27.99, 41.98, 55.98, 69.97, 83.97, 97.97, 111.96, 125.96, 139.95, 153.95]

new_length = 25
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

Comment: Instead of `sorted()` you could have just used `x1.reverse()` and `y1.reverse()`.

Comment: In this example the x1,y1 pairs are broken by sorting ONLY the x1 array. The y1 array should be shuffled the same way as the x1 array is.

Answer (score 14):

You can get this in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x1 = [1., 0.88,  0.67,  0.50,  0.35,  0.27, 0.18,  0.11,  0.08,  0.04,  0.04,  0.02]
y1 = [0., 13.99, 27.99, 41.98, 55.98, 69.97, 83.97, 97.97, 111.96, 125.96, 139.95, 153.95]

# Combine lists into list of tuples
points = zip(x1, y1)

# Sort list of tuples by x-value
points = sorted(points, key=lambda point: point[0])

# Split list of tuples into two list of x values any y values
x1, y1 = zip(*points)

new_length = 25
new_x = np.linspace(min(x1), max(x1), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x1, y1, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

Comment: Using above code, I'm getting this error in the last line, using Python 3.6: `ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.`

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye For me, it works fine with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. I have numpy 1.11 and scipy 0.17.0. Which versions do you use?

Comment: Indeed with Python 3.5 numpy 1.11.3 and scipy 0.17.1 it works. It also works with scipy 0.18.1 and numpy 1.11.3, but then breaks with scipy 0.19.1. Apparently, `interp1d` is now deprecated anyway.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: thanks. [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) does not seem to be deprecated, but indeed it fails at scipy 0.19, and works with 0.18.1.

Comment: See discussion here, interp1d is now UnivariateSpline https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4304

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the above error and fixed it with remove duplicated value in the X and Y array.

```
x = np.sort(np.array([0, .2, .2, .4, .6, .9]))
y = np.sort(np.sort(np.array([0, .1, .06, .11, .25, .55]))
```

⬇ Change *0.2* to *0.3* or any number.

```
x = np.sort(np.array([0, .2, .3, .4, .6, .9]))
y = np.sort(np.sort(np.array([0, .1, .06, .11, .25, .55]))
```